# Media codec 4.1 Issue

Tags: android, media, android-mediacodec

It works fine on most of the devices except nexus5, moto G as per my testing. on these devices app  producing video with only two frames.and also getting the following error log

[OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers   (output) failed w/ err -2147483648

Could you please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: As noted in the answer from Marlon, the error message doesn't actually indicate a failure.  You need to provide significantly more detail about what you're trying to do and what isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

from http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q12

Q12. Why am I seeing storeMetaDataInBuffers failures in the log?
A12. They look like this (example from a Nexus 5):

```
E OMXNodeInstance: OMX_SetParameter() failed for StoreMetaDataInBuffers: 0x8000101a
E ACodec  : [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -2147483648
```

**You can ignore them, they're harmless.**